# HTML is not rendering properly in Django

Tags: html, django

I am Naive in Django and HTML and trying to build an App using django. I got to know about the website getbootstrap.com . And I was trying to render the dropdown button from there in my index.html file.

The code for the Dropdown button is as follows.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And I am expecting a button like below:

[image]

But I am getting the The button as follows:

[image]

I want to know where I am going wrong?

**Update 1**

I have my index.html file inside template folder as follows:

**create_user** is my app that I am building and **ops_solution_v0** is the project that I am working on

[image]

Comment: check the css file are loading successfully and has the required styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to add cdn link to your index.html file.

Simply you can add like below code in your index.html file:

```
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

Add above cdn link inside head tag in your index file.

You output will appear as you expected